# MailChimp Form is loading page on Submit

Tags: php, api, mailchimp

I'm using the following on my site from MailChimp to submit a form:

```
<span id="response"><? require_once('inc/store-address.php'); if($_GET['submit']){ echo storeAddress(); } ?></span>
<form id="subform" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">

            <fieldset>
              <p>
                <input name="email" id="email" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" value="Email"  class="required email" />
              </p>
              <div class="button button-orange"> <span class="form_button clearfix">
                <input type="submit" class="sub_submit" name="submit" value="subscribe" />
                </span> </div>
              <div id="result_sub"></div>
            </fieldset>
          </form>
```

And everything is working fine, except when it submits, it reloads the WHOLE page. How do I prevent this?

Comment: That's normal, I think AJAX is what you are looking for if you don't want to leave the page when you submit the form.

Comment: that's how server side programming works.

Answer (score 0):

That's normal (and there's nothing you can do about it), but I'm pretty sure Mail Chimp has an option that allows you to control what page the user goes to after clicking submit.